# Use a lambda as a parameter for a C++ function

Tags: c++, function, c++11, lambda

I would like to use a lambda as a parameter for a C++ function, but I don't know which type to specify in the function declaration. What I would like to do is this:

```
void myFunction(WhatToPutHere lambda){
    //some things
}
```

I have tried `void myFunction(auto lambda)` and `void myFunction(void lambda)` but none of these codes compiled. In case it matters, the lambda doesn't return anything.

How can I use a lambda as a parameter in a C++ function?

Comment: Use a `std::function<>` parameter.

Comment: Does any of this change if the function in question is a member of a class?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You have 2 ways: make your function template:

```
template <typename F>
void myFunction(F&& lambda)
{
    //some things
}
```

or erase type (with [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) for example):

```
void
myFunction(const std::function<void()/*type of your lamdba::operator()*/>& f)
{
    //some things
}
```

Comment: Note that the former generates a new clone of your function per each different lambda that you pass to it throughout your program, and can't easily be used (probably not at all) for functions that you want to define in a separate compilation unit.

Comment: Note that the second solution will induce quite some runtime overhead and will do dynamic allocation. As the first solution is as fast as if you put the content on the lambda inside `myFunction`

Comment: How should I implement the function in a separate file (cpp) for the first version?

Comment: @X.Arthur: You cannot.

Comment: @Jarod42 You mean I cannot do explicit instantiation in a cpp file similar to what can be done for normal types?

Comment: @X.Arthur: Lambda types are unnamed, so hard to provide explicit instantiation with them. Creating several `myFunction`A-Z declaration, and putting definition in cpp which forward to the template with appropriate lambda would be possible.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Could you elaborate a little more? What does _"put the content on the lambda inside `myFunction`"_ mean?

Comment: @starriet I just meant inlining. `std::function` has the price of a virtual call or more. A template has the price of a normal function call or less.

Answer (score 27):

You have two choices, basically.

Make it a template:

```
template<typename T>
void myFunction(T&& lambda){
}
```

or, if you do not want (or can't) do that, you can use type-erased `std::function`:

```
void myFunction(std::function<void()> const& lambda){
}
```

---

Conversely, your attempt with `auto` would've been correct under the concepts TS as currently implemented in gcc, where it'd be an [abbreviated template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Abbreviated_templates).

```
// hypothetical C++2x code
void myFunction(auto&& lambda){
}
```

or with a concept:

```
// hypothetical C++2x code
void myFunction(Callable&& lambda){
}
```

Comment: For the template version, what's the advantange over void myFunction(T& lambda) or void myFunction(const T& lambda) ?

Comment: The usual forwarding reference advantage: you don't have to implement the function for const and non-const overloads if you aim to support non-const `operator()`. That being said, most, if not all, of the stdlib algorithms take the function object by copy, so maybe there's no reason to account for this case in general.

Answer (score 5):

Pass it as you'd pass a simple function. Just give it a name with `auto`

```
#include <iostream>

int SimpleFunc(int x) { return x + 100; }
int UsingFunc(int x, int(*ptr)(int)) { return ptr(x); }
auto lambda = [](int jo) { return jo + 10; };

int main() {
    std::cout << "Simple function passed by a pointer: " << UsingFunc(5, SimpleFunc) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Lambda function passed by a pointer: " << UsingFunc(5, lambda) << std::endl;

}
```

**Output:**
*Simple function passed by a pointer: 105

Lambda function passed by a pointer: 15*

Answer (score 3):

If this is an `inline` function, prefer a template, as in

```
template<typename Func>
void myFunction(Func const&lambda)
{
    //some things
}
```

because it binds to anything that makes sense (and will cause compiler error for anything else), including lambdas, instances of named classes, and `std::function<>` objects.

On the other hand, if this function is not `inline`, i.e. implemented in some compilation unit, you cannot use a generic template but must use a specified type, which is best taken a `std::function<>` object and passed via reference.